# why would a command run at the prompt and not in a script?

Tags: x11, raspbian, startx, xinit

I have a RPi running raspbian jessie which I use in kiosk mode: I start in `/etc/rc.local`

```
/usr/bin/xinit /opt/domotique/xinitrc > /root/xinitrc-errors 2>&1
```

and  `/opt/domotique/xinitrc` is

```
date > /tmp/date.txt
export DISPLAY=':0'
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
setxkbmap fr
/usr/bin/matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no -use_cursor no &
# wait for the window manager to start
sleep 10
rm -fr /root/.config /root/.cache
/usr/bin/firefox http://127.0.0.1:8081/infoscreen/infoscreen.html &
# let the browser start
sleep 10
/usr/bin/xte 'mousemove 10000 10000'
sleep 2
/usr/bin/xdotool key F11
date >> /tmp/date.txt
sleep 40000000
```

The idea is to start a minimal window manager, then firefox and then programatically move the mouse away and press `F11` to go fullscreen.

Everything works fine, except that the `F11` key is not "pressed" - I am left with firefox together with its chrome.

If I ssh to the host and run at the root prompt

```
export DISPLAY=':0'
/usr/bin/xdotool key F11
```

then firefox is correctly switched to full screen. Same if I use `xte`. The control file `/tmp/date.txt` has two date lines and there are no errors in `/root/xinitrc-errors`.

**What could be the reason for this strange behaviour?**

Comment: Could you try running `xdotool getmouselocation` and `xdotool getwindowfocus`, just before the `key F11`, to check that the mouse has moved and the right window is going to receive the input?  You may also get better results by using the same tool (`xte` or `xdotool`) for both opeations, rather than mixing the two.

Comment: @JigglyNaga: that was it - the focus. Somehow the focus was not there for the F11 to be accepted and after adding a xdotool windowfocus --sync `/usr/bin/xdotool search firefox | tail -1` it worked fine. Can you please turn your suggestion into an answer so that I can accept it? (it is surprising that the call over ssh works but never mind)

Comment: You could also use [wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/wait.html) instead of `sleep`ing for 15 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [xdotool(1)](http://manpages.org/xdotool):

> **key** *[options] keystroke [keystroke ...]*
>
> Options:
>
> **--window window**
>
> Send keystrokes to a specific window id. You can use ``WINDOW STACK'' references like ``%1'' and ``%@'' here. If there is a window stack, then ``%1'' is the default, otherwise the current window is used.

In your `ssh` test, you had already focused the Firefox window, so it received the keypress.  In the script, the `xte mousemove ...` left it unfocused.

You can chain `xdotool search` with other commands.  Searching for `firefox` may return multiple windows.  The manpage uses the example `--classname Navigator`, which works for the version I tested (47.0.1).  Failing that, you could use `xprop` to find some other string specific to the relevant window.

```
 xdotool search --classname Navigator windowfocus key F11
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your script, can you try putting the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```